# leaflet routing machine when waypoints are the same

Tags: leaflet

I am using this plugin : https://github.com/perliedman/leaflet-routing-machine.

My code looks like this:

```
for(let i=0; i<markers.length; i++){
  points.push(L.latLng(markers[i].latitude, markers[i].longitude))
}
this.routingControl = L.Routing.control({
  waypoints: points
}).addTo(this.map);
```

When I pass points filled with different latitude/longitude, it draws the route fine. But let's imagine the following scenario. let's say that points array contains 3 items. each item contains latitude/longitude and let's say that those latitude/longitude are the same. So something like this:

```
34.72581233927868     -80.71105957031251
34.72581233927868     -80.71105957031251 
34.72581233927868     -80.71105957031251
```

Now what Routing control does is as it can't draw the route, it automatically zooms in in the maximum way and in the console, it shows the errors.  **{"message":"Zoom level must be between 0-20."}**

Workaround 1: after drawing routes, i decided to use settimeout after 1 second and there I zoom at 11 by myseslf. this way it zooms out, but in the console, errors still stay. How do I fix this?

Comment: what is the version of routing machine?

Comment: leaflet-routing-machine": "^3.2.12

Comment: You could check before passing the points to the plugin that you are not in that case, ie that all the points are not the same. And submit an issue on the project page.

Answer (score 0):

If you know your input can be invalid, then the cleanest way would be to filter it on the way in to remove duplicates. If that's not possible for some reason and you want to let LRM determine if there's an error, then you can catch the error event with:

```
L.Routing.control({
...
})
.addTo(this.map)
.on('routingerror', function(e) {
    // do your error action here - e.g. zoom out
})
```

For more information on handling errors in LRM, see https://www.liedman.net/leaflet-routing-machine/api/#eventobjects